# Nested Navigation Stack does not find navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am want to add a secondary Navigation so that a subset of screens have access to providers, as opposed to the whole stack being wrapped by providers they do not need access to.  However, I think there is something wrong with my nested setup because I get an error when clicking a button that would navigate to the substack:

> ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"VehicleDetailInspections","params":{"vehicleId":27541}} was not handled by any navigator.

> Do you have a screen named 'VehicleDetailInspections'?

> If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

The link to this only shows tabs & drawers, which we do not have.

My setup is:

HOMESTACK

```
const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator<HomeStackParams>();

export function HomeNavigator(): JSX.Element {
  const styles = useInspectionStyles();

  return (
    <VehicleDataProvider>
      <HomeStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: styles.headerStyles,
          headerBackVisible: false,
          headerTitle: '',
          headerLeft: () => <GoBack />,
        }}
      >
        <HomeStack.Group
          screenOptions={{
            headerShadowVisible: false,
            headerStyle: [styles.headerStyles],
          }}
        >
          <HomeStack.Screen
            name={VEHICLE_DETAIL}
            component={VEHICLE_DETAIL.component}
          />
        </HomeStack.Group>
        /* 
        // I have tried both of these options:
        <HomeStack.Group>
            {() => <InspectionNavigator />}
        </HomeStack.Group>
       // or
        <HomeStack.Screen
          name={'InspectionSubStack'}
          component={InspectionNavigator}
        />
        */
      </HomeStack.Navigator>
    </VehicleDataProvider>
  );
}
```

In the above `HomeStack`, in the `VEHICLE_DETAIL` screen, there is a button which when clicked navigates to `VEHICLE_DETAIL_INSPECTIONS` which is part of the `InspectionStack` below.

```
const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProp<InspectionStackParams>>();
...
onPress={() =>
  navigation.navigate('VEHICLE_DETAIL_INSPECTIONS', {
     vehicleId: vehicle.id,
  })
}
```

INSPECTION substack:

```
const InspectionStack = createNativeStackNavigator<InspectionStackParams>();

export function InspectionNavigator(): JSX.Element {
  const styles = useInspectionStyles();

  return (
    <InspectionsDataProvider>
      <InspectionProgresssProvider>
        <InspectionStack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: styles.headerStyles,
            headerBackVisible: false,
            headerTitle: '',
            headerLeft: () => <GoBack />,
          }}
        >
          <InspectionStack.Screen
            name={VEHICLE_DETAIL_INSPECTIONS}
            component={
              VEHICLE_DETAIL_INSPECTIONS.component
            }
          />
          <InspectionStack.Screen
            name={VEHICLE_INSPECTIONS_SECTION].name}
            component={
              VEHICLE_INSPECTIONS_SECTION.component
            }
          />
          <InspectionStack.Screen
            name={VEHICLE_INSPECTIONS_STEP}
            component={VEHICLE_INSPECTIONS_STEP.component}
          />
        </InspectionStack.Navigator>
      </InspectionProgresssProvider>
    </InspectionsDataProvider>
  );
}
```

What do I need to do to get the `InspectionNavigator` to be found by the `navigate()` from `HomeStack`?

Comment: Have you tried `navigate('InspectionSubStack', { screen: 'VEHICLE_DETAIL_INSPECTIONS', params: { vehicleId: vehicle.id } })`?

Comment: Will give it a go...Also, is this the best way to get providers to wrap certain screens of a stack?

Comment: Context?  Yeah, best to wrap as few screens as possible, this is good.

Comment: Your solution should be the answer.  I didn't see that in the docs, but found it.https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator